# Leave variable on last iteration of while loop

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am stuck at a situation in my code. A variable `$end_date` is iterating in a while loop for showing end date of five chapters. Now on the basis of this variable I have to show an alert box. My problem is when the last chapter's end date is found the alert box pops up which is not valid because for other four chapters the end date is extended. How can I leave end date for the last chapter only and alert box condition should not be matched. I have tried alot on this but can't make a logic for this. Help or advice will be appreciated.

```
  if((strtotime($today_date) >= strtotime($end_date) || ( $pass_count == 0 && $status_request != 2 && $status_request != 0 ) ) )
  {


 echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
       mess1='Your exam validity date has been expired. Click OK to request for extending your Quiz validity or you can ignore by clicking Cancel.'  

       x = confirm(mess1);
       if (x == true)  
   {
       window.location = 'validity_request_mail.php?userid=$userid ';    

   } 

       </SCRIPT>");

 }
```

Comment: The `language` attribute has been deprecated for a long time, and should not be used.

Comment: what while loop? There's no while loop in your code

Comment: @JaromandaX I haven't posted the whole script. $end_date is coming from a while loop.

Comment: well, good, so `$end_date` is correct then?

Comment: I just want to know how can I leave this end date variable for the 5th iteration of while loop

Comment: Please add your code for while loop so it wiil be easy to help

Comment: @PrasannaVenkatesh Actually its a huge page. Lot many things are happening in this. Posting it will be more complicated

Comment: The user has a fixed number of days to appear for the quizzes and failing to which the quizzes get blocked and permission from admin is required. Validity is extended only for chapters in which either he has failed or not appeared.In a case when the user has cleared Quiz for last chapter only and the validity is not extended to that chapter. The end date becomes the last chapter's clearing date and so after getting permission for rest of the chapters the user is asked again for permission.if the extension is given it should let the user take the quiz for rest of chapters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

We may introduce a new variable named `$last_date` which is for capturing the "greatest" end date of all chapters.

It seems that the problem is that after a `while()` loop, the `$end_date` is set, and it should be the last date.  However the last (5th iteration) has an `$end_date` before other `$end_date`(s) of other chapters, so showing the `confirm()` box is not correct (since there are some chapters that are not expired yet).

So this should fix it:

```
while (...) { 
    ... 
} 
... 
// snippet in OP's post
```

To:

```
$last_date = '';
while (...) { 
    ... 
    if ( strtotime($end_date) > strtotime($last_date) ) { 
        $last_date = $end_date; 
    } 
} 
... 
$end_date = $last_date; // continue with snippet in OP's post
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158967/discussion-on-answer-by-sunny-pun-leave-variable-on-last-iteration-of-while-loop).